# How can I print the "Hello world" every 2 seconds for 10 seconds in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I want to print a value (Like Hello world) with interval of 2 seconds till 10 second. How can I do it?

Comment: [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Answer (score 8):

Use `setInterval()` to print `Hello World` each 2 seconds, Use `setTimeout()` to clear the interval after 10 seconds.

```js
var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
  console.log('Hello World'); 
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function() { 
  clearInterval(interval); 
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But the problem is it print only 4 times, on 10000 value it got cleared.

Comment: What got cleared? It's printing 5 times in the code snippet console.

Comment: sometimes it's printing 5 times, sometimes it's printing 4 times:  just use 11000 instead of 10000 to avoid this

Answer (score 5):

Code:

```
var i=0;

var myfunc = setInterval(function(){

    i = i + 1;
    console.log('Hello World at '+ 2*i + ' seconds'); 

    if(i==5) {
        clearInterval(myfunc);
    }

}, 2000);
```

Output:

```
Hello World at 2 seconds  
Hello World at 4 seconds  
Hello World at 6 seconds  
Hello World at 8 seconds  
Hello World at 10 seconds
```

Comment: Because of length and content, this is marked as low quality. Providing the output will make this answer better. Also, looks like it needs to print 5 times as per OP (Im fixing this for this time). See comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337325/how-can-i-print-the-hello-world-every-2-seconds-for-10-seconds-in-node-js#comment79635029_46337564

Answer (score 0):

Use the setTimeout() function to schedule the future execution of a function.
The following example works but it is specifically written to make you get a bad evaluation if you use it for carrying out your homework

```
function myFunc(arg) {
  console.log(`${arg}`);
}

setTimeout(myFunc, 2000, 'Hello world');
setTimeout(myFunc, 4000, 'Hello world');
setTimeout(myFunc, 6000, 'Hello world');
setTimeout(myFunc, 8000, 'Hello world');
setTimeout(myFunc, 10000, 'Hello world');
```

Comment: Thankyou , but 10 seconds may vary.

Comment: You are welcome and you are wrong, my friend:  x seconds may vary, 10 seconds are immutable

Answer (score 0):

```
var noTimeout = 2000;
var newTime = 0;
var maxTime = 10000;

function next(timeout) {
    if (timeout == undefined)
        timeout = noTimeout
    setTimeout(processAuto, timeout);
}

function processAuto() {
    console.log("Hello world")
    newTime = newTime + noTimeout;
    if (newTime >= maxTime) {
        process.exit(0);
    } else {
        next(noTimeout);
    }
}
processAuto();
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives me an opportunity to play with [process.hrtime()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time) method.

```
let currentTime
let counter = 0

while (counter < 10) {
  if (counter === 0 || currentTime !== (currentTime = process.hrtime()[0])) {
    if (counter++ % 2) console.log("Hello world")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet for exact interval between each run.

```
setTimeout(function prn(i){
  console.log('Hello world');
  i++;
  if(i < 5){
    setTimeout(prn, 2000, i);
  }
}, 2000, 0);
```

and the below one for interval between start of each run.

```
var inter = setInterval(() => console.log('TCS'), 2000);
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(inter), 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inter = setInterval(() => console.log('Hello world'), 5000);
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(inter), 10000);
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var inter = setInterval(() => console.log('TCS'), 2000);
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(inter), 10000);
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps